# Is there a way to know whether a user is syncing contacts through iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-api

On iOS devices, is there a programmatic way to figure out if a user is syncing their contacts through iCloud? Or would this information be private?

If it is private, what would be a good way to figure out whether someone has contact syncing turned on?

Comment: I believe that all of that is private API. I think it would be better to *just ask* them if they have syncing enabled rather risking private APIs

Comment: I'm tempted to answer that title by saying ask the NSA or something.